# c3p0 for testing Connections taking too much time

Tags: jdbc, c3p0

In my case,
for testing connection c3p0 is taking too much time by executing query

```
SHOW FULL TABLES FROM `xyz` LIKE 'PROBABLYNOT'
```

while i am using mysql connector version 5.1.25. there is  driver supports the JDBC 4.
as i refered one link 
http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#configuring_connection_testing

where it is mentioned that

> If you are using a JDBC driver that you are certain supports the
>   new(ish) JDBC 4 API, do nothing. JDBC 4 Connections include a method
>   called isValid() that should be implemented as a fast, reliable
>   Connection test. By default, c3p0 will use that method if it is
>   present.

so my question is how i came to know that it is isvalid() method is used and which query is executed when c3p0 calls this method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The query you've shown definitely derives from c3p0's slow, default Connection test.

The docs you are using are for the latest version of c3p0, 0.9.5-pre8. You may not be using a recent enough version. (I should put a note in the docs indicating this.)

So... either upgrade to 0.9.5-pre8 (it's high quality, very close to release), or supply an efficient `preferredTestQuery` config param (`SELECT 1` seems to work for MySQL.)

Comment: thanx.i have upgraded it to 0.9.5-pre8 and it works. :)