# Why these c3p0 queries are running often in mysql

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, c3p0

below is the `c3p0` and `hibernate` configuration and i'm going through below issues.why are these queries are running continuously and how can I disable them.

**Hibernate and c3p0 configuration**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">
            com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
        </property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">
            jdbc:mysql://localhost/?autoReconnect=true
        </property>
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">dpSJtjixUinCDoV4ia6yCQ==</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">
            com.razorthink.runtime.RztMysqlDialect
        </property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class" >com.virima.connectionPool.CustomConnectionProvider</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">400</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">4</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">1</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">300</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">0</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">300</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_idle_time">2000</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_connection_age">6000</property>
        <property name="show_sql">false</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.isolation">2</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.CharSet">utf8</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">utf8</property>
    <mapping resource="h915211324.hbm.xml" />

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**Queries causing cpu hit are below**

```
2020-04-29T15:22:47.740540Z  5200 Query SHOW FULL TABLES FROM `emdb_1521702330190` LIKE 'PROBABLYNOT'
2020-04-29T15:22:47.740831Z  5187 Query SHOW FULL TABLES FROM `emdb_1521702330190` LIKE 'PROBABLYNOT'
2020-04-29T15:22:47.750197Z  5200 Query SHOW FULL TABLES FROM `emdb_1557220119370` LIKE 'PROBABLYNOT'
2020-04-29T15:22:47.750521Z  5187 Query SHOW FULL TABLES FROM `emdb_1557220119370` LIKE 'PROBABLYNOT'
2020-04-29T15:22:47.770292Z  5213 Query SHOW FULL TABLES FROM `emdb_1584082233309` LIKE 'PROBABLYNOT'
2020-04-29T15:22:47.775548Z  5279 Query SHOW FULL TABLES FROM `emdb_1563780179958` LIKE 'PROBABLYNOT'
2020-04-29T15:22:47.776983Z  5201 Query SHOW FULL TABLES FROM `emdb_1563780179958` LIKE 'PROBABLYNOT'
2020-04-29T15:22:47.778582Z  5234 Query SHOW FULL TABLES FROM `emdb_1584082233309` LIKE 'PROBABLYNOT'
2020-04-29T15:22:47.790130Z  5179 Query UPDATE `ta_cmdb_ci_relationships` SET target_ipaddress = '172.24.110.36',target_tags = '|8|',target_icon = null,target_location = '35 Adams Avenue',target_hostname = 'NOC-TRI-UAT-07',target_blueprint = 'Windows Server',target_ci_id=107611,target_host_ci_record_id='26e58509-a7c9-4fef-b5cf-d659a30b103e' WHERE target_id = 107611
2020-04-29T15:22:47.812510Z  5200 Query SHOW FULL TABLES FROM `emdb_1563774517358` LIKE 'PROBABLYNOT'
2020-04-29T15:22:47.812915Z  5187 Query SHOW FULL TABLES FROM `emdb_1563774517358` LIKE 'PROBABLYNOT'
2020-04-29T15:22:47.818616Z  5179 Query commit
2020-04-29T15:22:47.839903Z  5213 Query SHOW FULL TABLES FROM `information_schema` LIKE 'PROBABLYNOT'
2020-04-29T15:22:47.840200Z  5213 Query SHOW FULL TABLES FROM `management_db` LIKE 'PROBABLYNOT'
2020-04-29T15:22:47.844614Z  5213 Query SHOW FULL TABLES FROM `mysql` LIKE 'PROBABLYNOT'
2020-04-29T15:22:47.845308Z  5201 Query SHOW FULL TABLES FROM `emdb_1569887214264` LIKE 'PROBABLYNOT'
2020-04-29T15:22:47.845527Z  5279 Query SHOW FULL TABLES FROM `emdb_1569887214264` LIKE 'PROBABLYNOT'
2020-04-29T15:22:47.846760Z  5234 Query SHOW FULL TABLES FROM `information_schema` LIKE 'PROBABLYNOT'
2020-04-29T15:22:47.846970Z  5234 Query SHOW FULL TABLES FROM `management_db` LIKE 'PROBABLYNOT'
2020-04-29T15:22:47.847032Z  5213 Query SHOW FULL TABLES FROM `performance_schema` LIKE 'PROBABLYNOT'
2020-04-29T15:22:47.850979Z  5234 Query SHOW FULL TABLES FROM `mysql` LIKE 'PROBABLYNOT'
2020-04-29T15:22:47.855794Z  5213 Query SHOW FULL TABLES FROM `quartz_scheduler` LIKE 'PROBABLYNOT'
2020-04-29T15:22:47.856963Z  5234 Query SHOW FULL TABLES FROM `performance_schema` LIKE 'PROBABLYNOT'
2020-04-29T15:22:47.857565Z  5213 Query SHOW FULL TABLES FROM `sys` LIKE 'PROBABLYNOT'
2020-04-29T15:22:47.864297Z  5234 Query SHOW FULL TABLES FROM `quartz_scheduler` LIKE 'PROBABLYNOT'
2020-04-29T15:22:47.867085Z  5234 Query SHOW FULL TABLES FROM `sys` LIKE 'PROBABLYNOT'
2020-04-29T15:22:47.869482Z  5213 Query select * from ar_data
2020-04-29T15:22:47.875941Z  5187 Query SHOW FULL TABLES FROM `emdb_1563780179958` LIKE 'PROBABLYNOT'
2020-04-29T15:22:47.876417Z  5200 Query SHOW FULL TABLES FROM `emdb_1563780179958` LIKE 'PROBABLYNOT'
2020-04-29T15:22:47.877967Z  5253 Query SHOW DATABASES
2020-04-29T15:22:47.879442Z  5234 Query SHOW DATABASES
2020-04-29T15:22:47.880157Z  5253 Query SHOW FULL TABLES FROM `async_data` LIKE 'PROBABLYNOT'
2020-04-29T15:22:47.882533Z  5234 Query SHOW FULL TABLES FROM `async_data` LIKE 'PROBABLYNOT'
2020-04-29T15:22:47.901594Z  5279 Query SHOW FULL TABLES FROM `emdb_1584082233309` LIKE 'PROBABLYNOT'
2020-04-29T15:22:47.912542Z  5201 Query SHOW FULL TABLES FROM `emdb_1584082233309` LIKE 'PROBABLYNOT'
```

Answer (score 0):

since c3p0 is a connection pool it needs to know if the connections are still alive and ready to be used by the application. In order to get this information it executes test query to check if the connection was not closed from the other side.

So it is better now to remove such mechanism in general or you will periodically see errors in the logs when application will attempt to execute real query and connection is already in stale state.

But since this connection test is slow you can change the query to something different. Plz check `preferredTestQuery` attribute of c3p0.

Here [c3p0 for testing Connections taking too much time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24550730/c3p0-for-testing-connections-taking-too-much-time) it is also an advice to upgrade the version of c3p0 to get this feature working better.